# selenium java load image in for xlink:href attribute

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to load images in one website, but I didn't succeed,

This is the Source Code when pressing F12

```
    <div class="styles_slide__1WxkV">
    <div class="styles_item__2z_U9 styles_btnLoaded__3cD1S" data-position="1">
    <span class="styles_imageAdded__nbDDD">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sc-bdVaJa src___StyledBox-fochin-0 dCYVFu">
    <title>conteneur de l'image</title>
    <use xlink:href="#SvgCameraoutline"></use>
    </svg>
    </span><span class="_2QIe0 _1rwR5 _1pJw9 _137P- P4PEa _35DXM">Photo n°1</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

However I tried many codes :

-

```
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='pictures'] div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2)"));
        Actions act2=new Actions(driver);
        act2.moveToElement(element).sendKeys("C:\\url\\test.jpg").perform();

 - 



    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='pictures'] div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(1) span:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("C:\\url\\test.jpg");
       
- 



    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(1) > main:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > section:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > svg:nth-child(1)")).sendKeys("C:\\url\\sac.jpg");

- 



   

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'styles_item__2z_U9')]")).sendKeys("C:\\url\\sac.jpg");

-



    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='use' and @*='#SvgCameraoutline']")).sendKeys("C:\\url\\sac.jpg");

-



    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//svg[contains(@class, 'sc-bdVaJa')]")).sendKeys("C:\\url\\sac.jpg");
```

But anyone of them is working with, can you help me please,
This is the code source extract of the webpage which I would like to automate by loading images in it.

I am trying to automate one stuff boring (add a post) in this website (url removed)

Then click on "deposer-une-annonce" and follow steps until come to one step to load images, in this step I can't load image automatically by using selenium java as I explained above

Comment: I strongly suggest you not to share any kind of passwords within your posts...

Comment: @KemalKaplan it is juste for only test I don't use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one input tag that has type as file.

But I couldn't figure out your website, so I could not enable that input field.

But I believe if you `send_keys` to **Quel est le titre de l’annonce ?** with some other input, it may help you past this issue.

Anyway to upload an image, you can use the below css selector :-

```
input[type='file']
```

and in code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")).sendKeys("C:\\url\\test.jpg");
```

or with **Explicit waits :**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))).sendKeys("C:\\url\\test.jpg");
```

Comment: I don't want send_keys to `Quel est le titre de l’annonce ?`, in this step I have no problem because I send only some text in this input field so if you want to figure out you must continue the test until the reach the page which you can load images, so in this step I would like to automate this loading of image there is no input tag, I pasted the Source Code when pressing F12 above in my post

Comment: tell me how do I reach there ? `you must continue the test until the reach the page which you can load images,`

Comment: After logIn using 
`Login : fortest08@outlook.fr`
`Password: ForTest123`
click on `Déposer une annonce` button, then put text in the `Quel est le titre de l’annonce ?` input like `sac de voyage` then click on `continuer` button after that chose a category like `Mode>Accessoires & Bagagerie` then click on `continue` button, after that put a text on `Description de l'annonce` texterea like `sac de voyage neuf` then click on the `continuer` button after that click on again on the `continuer` button and then click on `continuer` button again so here you reach the page which you can load images

Comment: okay I got it. Thanks for brief explanation, and still I do see `input[type='file']` on the page where you want to upload a pic, once you reach there, you don't have to trigger `.click()` on `Ajouter des photos` Web element. just try the above code and see if that helps, if there's an error, let me know. or else you can try with explicit wait as well, `new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))).sendKeys("C:\\url\\test.jpg");`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate that, I have just one question how did you find that `input[type='file']` or do you use any tools or plugins to help you to do that, for me I found the Source Code above on my post when pressing F12 how did you find `input[type='file']` please and thank you so much

Comment: when we press F12 we go to dev tools, and if you then go to Element section, and do CTRL+F, you will see a input search bar. Now, writing `input[type='file']` is a skill, unfortunately there are no tools available which could generate this dynamically. Basically  if you pay attention that is `tag_name[attribute_name='attribute_value']`, you can construct your css selector like this

Comment: Ok thanks I found it, I know one plugin maybe that will help you, it called : selectoresHub